# How to enable remote desktop connection in Ubuntu 9.04 using command line. ( Using Putty)

Tags: putty

How to enable remote desktop connection in Ubuntu 9.04 using Putty?

Comment: When you say "remote desktop," does that mean you're asking specifically for how to forward RDP connections over SSH using PuTTY? Also, on which machine are you running PuTTY--the Ubuntu machine, or the other machine? And is the Ubuntu machine the client (connecting to the other machine), or is the other machine the client (so you're connecting to Ubuntu)? Is the other machine running Windows? Please **edit your question** to expand and clarify it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you can not login to your Ubuntu using putty, Install `sshd` first there.

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If you want to have access to the desktop of Ubuntu install `vnc` there.

```
apt-get install vnc4server
```

Then configure `vnc`.

Answer (score 0):

Install the ssh deamon.

```
sudo apt-get install sshd
```

See also [this howto](http://thinkhole.org/wp/2006/10/30/five-steps-to-a-more-secure-ssh/) to secure your system. Also it is a good idea to secure your system with fail2ban.